# Is there any validity to missing a minyan due to your job?

Tags: minyan, employment

If one’s job requires them to work from the time mincha starts until past Shkiya, is there any source that allows one to work and not attend minyan?
How far does one have to “push” in order to leave work to go to a mincha minyan?
Would the answer change if instead of minyan, it was time to daven at all?

Comment: Who said they are allowed to break to pray at all, let alone leave to a minyan?

Comment: Rabbi Willig is on the record that a restaurant mashgiach whose shift runs from mid-day till past sunset should *not* go to a scheduled minyan -- that means everyone else in the restaurant will know when he isn't looking! He should instead daven on his own at an unpredictable time. He also has stated that if someone's college classes mean they can't daven mincha with a minyan, they should daven on their own and attend all of their classes.

Comment: @Shalom great source but seems maybe that’s davka a mashgiach because it would be bad if people knew he wasn’t around. Perhaps things would change in other situations?

Comment: @DoubleAA my question centers around how far you have to go to get that permission. Must you quit if you know you’ll *never* be able to daven?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99

Comment: @DoubleAA is your Raya from Seif Beis that a Po’el should say Shemoneh Esrei but the SA doesn’t mention anything about minyan?